# Merge multiple object in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, object

I have one or more object in foreach and I want to merge all the objects in one in `$refJSON`.

```
$refObj = (object) array();

foreach($items as $item) { //here Im looping Two items
    $refObj->refId = $item->getId();
    $refObj->refLastName = $item->getLastName();
    $refObj->refPhone = $item->getPhone();
    $orderObj->refEmail = $item->getEmail();
}

$refJSON = json_encode($orderObj);
var_dump($refJSON);
```

Output :

```
//just the last item object
string(92) "{
              "refId":"2",
              "refLastName":"Joe",
              "refPhone":"xxxxxxx",
              "refEmail":"example@domaine.com"
             }"
```

The output expected is to merge all the items ids 1 and 2 something like this:

```
[
  {
     "refId":"1",
     "refLastName":"Steve",
     "refPhone":"xxxxxxx",
     "refEmail":"foo@domaine.com"
  },
  {
    "refId":"2",
    "refLastName":"Joe",
    "refPhone":"xxxxxxx",
    "refEmail":"example@domaine.com"
  }

]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just overwriting the same object each time.  Build each object and add this to an array (using `[]`) and encode the result...

```
$refOut = array();

foreach($items as $item) { //here Im looping Two items
    $refOut[] = ['refId' => $item->getId(),
        'refLastName' => $item->getLastName(),
        'refPhone' => $item->getPhone(),
        'refEmail' => $item->getEmail()];
}

$refJSON = json_encode($refOut);
```